# How to reassign const variable to true if condition is met in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

How can I reassign a const to true if a condition is met in react? It keeps showing an error of **'displayInternalForm' is declared but its value is never read**.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

  const displayInternalForm = false;

  const internalJob = internalcategory.categories.find((cat) => 
                      cat.id?.includes("a5c26877-e89c-440b-b7a0-31552865fff5"));

  if (internalJob !== undefined) {
    // It is not reading this line of code. 
    const displayInternalForm = true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `let` if a variable is reassigned.

Read More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let?retiredLocale=de)

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

  let displayInternalForm = false;

  const internalJob = internalcategory.categories.find((cat) => 
                      cat.id?.includes("a5c26877-e89c-440b-b7a0-31552865fff5"));

  if (internalJob !== undefined) {
    // It is not reading this line of code. 
   displayInternalForm = true;
  }

}
```